# SCCM keeps deployng even it was removed

Tags: deployment, sccm

**Problem:** System Center Endpoint Protection keeps deploying itself from SCCM to the computers and servers after I manually delete them, even if the SCCM server got completely removed recently. Though AFAIK the deployment tasks weren't deleted, only the services stopped and SCCM related programs uninstalled. Also the server (Hostname: SCCM_SERVER) was shutdown.

[image]
If I open one of the servers and go to Configuration Manager, I see that Assigned management point is still SCCM_SERVER.

[image]

**Question:** Not having been delved into SCCM administration prior, how is this happening? Did it create windows services on each machine? Could there be additional SCCM administration sever running somewhere else? I checked GPO/scheduled tasks - nothing. How does the deployment work? And how do I stop it?

Also, if additional information related to the software/hardware/network is required please ask.

Regards,

Sai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the log file EndpointProtectionAgent.log? Maybe it can give us some clues.

If you want to decommission SCCM, you could uninstall the SCCM client.

The correct way is edit the Client Settings node in the Administration workspace first.

Modify the device settings "Install Endpoint Protection client on client computers", choosing False or No will not uninstall the Endpoint Protection client. To uninstall the Endpoint Protection client, set the Manage Endpoint Protection client on client computers client setting to False or No. Then, deploy a package and program to uninstall the Endpoint Protection client.

[#About client settings in System Center Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/core/clients/deploy/about-client-settings#endpoint-protection)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know SCCM client would stay active after the main SCCM is taken down. Turns out it stores installer files on the client, rather than downloading every time.